# ajaxForum plugin post parameter

Tags: jquery, plugins, parameters, ajaxform

Hei there, I started using ajaxForm plugin, having the form statement like this:

```
<form id="upload" action="upload.php" methor="POST">
<!-- form inputs etc etc -->
</form>
```

All working fine, but if I try to change action parameter from "upload.php" to "upload.php?some_param=value" it calls just upload.php, anyone has any ideas on how can I send another param with ajaxForm ?

I looked up through the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#upload').live('change',function() {
$(this).ajaxForm({
success: somefunction, // callback function
//i guess here should be another parameter to be sent to the file, but I couldn't find anything interesting on the web
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Figured out why it doesn't work by just simply adding action="file.php?key=parameter" , because the form is submitted via POST, and the key string in the action parameter can be read by $_GET['key'] in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a hidden field inside the form with the value you want posted:

```
<form id="upload" action="upload.php" method="POST">
    <!-- form inputs etc etc -->
    <input type="hiden" value="value" id="some_param" name="some_param" />
</form>
```

This should *post the value of the hidden field when you post the form*